# RC Transmitter for DIY

Tags: quadcopter

A couple of years ago I bought a WLToys V222 quadcopter.
[image]
I would like to know if there is a way to use the transmitter to control some DIY projects?

Does anyone know how I could do that?

Comment: your question is very broad.

Comment: My intent is that the question is very specific.  How do I create a receiver that can be can act off signals from the V222 transmitter?  I am sure they must use some sort of a standard protocol.  I believe knowing this would be big help to the general community as these transmitters are really inexpensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up the quadcopter and Identified the chips it uses

- [Mini54 microcontroller](http://www.icbase.com/File/PDF/NUV/NUV00161201.pdf)
- [MPU-6050 Motion Tracking Device](https://www.invensense.com/products/motion-tracking/6-axis/mpu-6050/)
- [BK2423 2.4 GHz Transceiver](http://www.inhaos.com/uploadfile/otherpic/BK2423%20Datasheet%20v2.0.pdf)

Based on this, I found the NRF24L01 which appeared to be compatible which I purchased on eBay for a whopping $0.67US

After a bit of time and part in hand I hooked it up to an Arduino and I was able to control a servo using my inexpensive wireless controller.

[image: My Setup]

**SUCCESS!!**

If you would like more information, Up Vote this and add a comment.

Comment: BTW, I have seen this same transmitter new on eBay for $11 and I imaging you could find smaller and/or used ones for even less; so, it is a pretty inexpensive